# C#, If Statement, Min and Max

Tags: c#

Good evening; I am writing a bit of code that solves the following equation.

X is size of device
Y is quantity of device
A is the denominator
Z is the total diversified value

(X * Y)/A = Z

Here is the part I don't know how to accomplish. The value of A is found by the amount of Y. If Y is between 3 and 6 than A = .7, if Y is between 6 and 9 than A = .6; and so on.

What function should I use to accomplish the above?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Greg Rutledge

Comment: No, its a small calculator for some of the guys at work.

Comment: -1: Poorly titled question. I'd have edited the title rather than downvoted if I could figure out what the OP is even asking.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know what I need to use to get the correct answer. I'm sorry. I will try to better understand what I am looking for and revise.

Comment: Greg - based on your title and the content of your question, it is difficult to really understand the problem you are trying to solve without some more background.  Your title seems to indicate you have something in mind already.  Give the community more to work with and you may find more success.

Comment: Thank you very much John. I will post some code very soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 approaches to this, IMO:

1) Formula calculation.  Thus, you want to know what A is given Y which if you have enough data, e.g. taking your .7 for 3<=Y<6, .6 for 6

```
A = .8-(Y/3)/10.0;
```

You may need to use a cast or truncate function on the Y/3 part if Y isn't a multiple of 3, or you could do this to take out the fractional part: (Y-(Y % 3))/3

2) Use a while loop structure to take out the 3's of Y, note that the statements in the while are abbreviated which may make it a bit unclear:

```
int Holder = Y, A=.8;
while (Holder > 0)
{
    A-= .1;
    Holder-= 3;
}
```

3) If/elseif.  If Y is bounded then there is a brute force assignment strategy you could use:

```
 If Y<3 
    A=.8
 Else if Y < 6 
    A=.7
 Else if Y < 9 
    A=.6
```

etc.

This is in order of what I'd consider for solving such a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use if and the comparison operators (<=). Homework?

What do you mean by "and so on"? If the cases are regular then maybe you can use a formula instead of a bunch of if statements.

```
if(Y <= 3.0)      A = ...; 
else if(Y <= 6.0) A = 0.7; 
else if(Y <= 9.0) A = 0.6;
...
```

Comment: No, its a calculator for some of the guys at work to use as a reference. It is meant to figure the diversified value of group mounted devices in an electrical panel. I know it looks like homework and I am sorry about that.

Comment: The and so on is because there are two more criteria that will produce a different denominator.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming A starts at 0.8 and decreases by 0.1 with every increase by 3 of Y:

```
int temp = Y / 3;
float A = 0.8f - (temp / 10f);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, taking the code that you just posted, I think this is what you're looking for:

```
if ((cb5_1.Checked)&&(cb5_2.Checked)&&(cb5_3.Checked))
{
    //if the first three text boxes are checked calculate based on the following. 
    decimal a, b, c, d, z;
    decimal aa, bb, cc, zz;
    a = decimal.Parse(cbx5_1a.Text);
    b = decimal.Parse(cbx5_2a.Text);
    c = decimal.Parse(cbx5_3a.Text);
    aa = decimal.Parse(cbx5_1q.Text);
    bb = decimal.Parse(cbx5_2q.Text);
    cc = decimal.Parse(cbx5_3q.Text);
    z = (aa+bb+cc);

    d = 0.8m - ((z / 3) / 10m);

    zz = ((a*aa)+(b*bb)+(c*cc))*d;

    tb5_atotal.Text = Math.Round(z,2).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the values are predefined in a list, and not created with a function.

Basically each object has a minValue, maxValue, value, minLink and maxLink.

Follow links until you find the target value or a null pointer.

```
if Y <= maxValue then 
    if Y >= minValue then
        return value
    else
        follow minLink
else 
    follow maxLink
```